# How to change location of `My Documents` folder on Windows 10 when `Location` tab is not present?

Tags: windows-10, redirection, user-folders

How to change location of `My Documents` folder on Windows 10 when `Location` tab is not present in Dialog Box displayed after having clicked `Properties` contextual menu linked to `My Documents` folder as visible in following printscreen and as explained in [Symbolic link two users document and desktop folders](https://superuser.com/questions/1469688/symbolic-link-two-users-document-and-desktop-folders/1469698)

[image]

Translation explanations:

```
Général = Common 
Partage = Share
Sécurité = Security
Versions précédentes = Previous versions
Personnaliser = Customize
```

If it is impossible to restore `Location` Tab visibility, how can I redirect `My Documents` folder to `D:\Documents` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you're not seeing a **Location** tab because the folder is not designated as one of the User Shell folders.

To check, in the **Explorer** Address bar, copy & paste or type the following commands one at a time to verify the location assigned to the Shell folders:

```
Shell:Personal
Shell:Local Documents
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer don't solve my problem because (before deleting registry key) it is not possible to modify location of 'Documents' folder that is display in my Personal folder. You explain only 'why' but my question is 'how' ! But I like (voteup) your explanation on 'shell' command in File Explorer.

Comment: So what were the paths for the folder(s) opened by the `Shell` commands? If they didn't open to the folder in question (**Documents** in **Personal**), then, as far as the OS is concerned, **Documents** is just an ordinary file folder, despite its name. To "relocate" it, you would move it like any normal file folder.

Comment: If this **Documents** folder is the folder you want designated as the _User Shell Folder_, you would use the **Location** tab in the **Properties** of the folder opened by the `Shell` commands given earler and relocate _that _ folder to `C:\Users\bema\Documents`. Then the **Properties** dialog for  `C:\Users\bema\Documents` will have a **Location** tab.

Answer (score 1):

The `Documents` folder is linked to `Microsoft OneDrive` product and don't have possibilities to change `Location` because this tab is not there.

I have checked following registry key

```
  \HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    \Software
      \Microsoft
        \Windows
          \CurrentVersion
            \Explorer
              \User Shell Folders
```

and I have found one numbered key between { and } that contains the same folder path.

I have deleted this entry in registry. I have reboot and now I can click active `Properties` contextual menu of `Documents` folder and I can see the `Location` tab.

The problem happens because Microsoft has added a `User Shell` folder in registry that has deactivated/replaced standard User Documents folder.

Comment: Would it not be easier to disable the OneDrive feature that added the registry key rather then manually edit the registry.  You don’t specify which key you removed

Comment: I have removed a numbered key between { and } it is not a named key. But it is now impossible for me to retrieve it; it is deleted from registry and I don't have a recent backup of my registry.

Answer (score 0):

Open My Documents and then on the Desktop icon or Documents icon on the left, right click and choose Properties. Location in on that tab.

I highly recommend keeping My Documents on Drive C as I have found over time that Windows works better this way

Comment: When I right click on Desktop icon, 'Location' tab is not displayed ! That is my question ! Why on my PC, location tab is not there ?

Comment: Did you open up Desktop so you can see folders on the right. The way you describe (as I read it) Location is not a tab. Same here. But open it up and then within Windows Explorer, right click on Desktop / Documents on the left and then Location is a tab. Two different ways to get at it, one shows Location and the other way does not show Location

Comment: I have checked and I can see LOCATION tab for image but not for DOCUMENTS folder that is linked to OneDrive ! But that help me to find the solution. I will now post an answer.

Comment: See `My Documents` in Nirsoft's *Special Folder View* for some idea where that reference is stored. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html